# My Payroll program outputs the wrong calculation for the total of salary

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a prototype payroll system.

Every time I put the required information for the calculations, it always outputs the wrong information (I always check with a calculator).

It doesn't have any errors or warnings so I think the problem is how I format the code.

Can someone please teach me how to fix this problem?

**Note: The program is incomplete.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#define SYSERROR()  GetLastError()
#else
#include <errno.h>
#define SYSERROR()  errno
#endif


struct Employees//Not in use yet
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
};

class Salary_variables
{
public:
    long days = 0;
    long overtime = 0;
    long basic_pay = 537;
    long overtime_pay = 80.1375;
    long regular_salary = days * basic_pay;
    long compute()//constructor for determining the employee's salary
    {
        if (overtime == 0)
        {
            return regular_salary;
        }
        else if (overtime >= 0)
        {
            long overtime_salary = overtime * overtime_pay;
            return regular_salary + overtime_salary;
        }
     }
};



int main()
{
    Employees employee;
    std::cout << "Type in employee's full name:\n";
    std::cin >> employee.first_name >> employee.last_name;

    Salary_variables variables;
    std::cout << "Type in total amount of days worked:\n";
    std::cin >> variables.days;

    std::cout << "Type in total amount of overtime hours worked:\n";
    std::cin >> variables.overtime;

    std::cout << "Total salary: " << variables.compute() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The member `long regular_salary = days * basic_pay;` That's not going to magically recompute `regular_salary` just because you change the value of `days` via an input read. Frankly I don't see the sense in the `regular_salary` member whatsoever, and in fact, the two `if` conditions. You should be able to just `return days * basic_pay + overtime * overtime_pay;` If there was no overtime, the latter half of that expression adds nothing to the computed result.

Comment: You made overtime_pay a long and yet you assign a double. That will result in truncation of the value to 80.

Comment: Wow, after reading the post replies, I'm feeling very stupid. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 big mistakes in your code, but without examples of input and output it is possible I missed more.

The biggest error is that you are using `long` - which is an integer type!
You need to use `double` so that the decimal part of the salary will be preserved in the calculation.

For example, using `long` 10 hours of overtime would be worth `80 * 10 = 800`.
But, with the correct calculation using double, `80.1375 * 10.0 = 801.375`.

Also, as others already mentioned, you must do the multiplication inside the `compute` function.

Member variable initialization happens only once when you create an instance of the class.
So your code multiplies the salary by 0 on line `Salary_variables variables;`.

If you change the `days` variable afterwards, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

The below initialization should be done inside compute function:

`long regular_salary = days * basic_pay;`

Otherwise, it will initialize the variable with default values when creating class variable.